# Import colab notebooks from google drive to another colab notebook

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have mounted the google drive to google colab but don't know how to import and use other colab notebooks now.

What I want to do is to replace 'model.pkl' to the address of my notebook stored in google drive.

`model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))`